# Maps API Places Autocomplete dropdown shows city, but autofills city field with township?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We’re coming across address that our Google address API is updating to something other than what it suggest.

Here’s what for example:

576 Shunpike Road
Cape May Court House, NJ 08210

So when you start filling in the address, it gives this as an option

[Cape May Court House in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghOL.png)

But when you select that, you get this, which is not a deliverable address according to Shippo/UPS shipping integration.

[Middle Township autofills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZe6D.png)

Some more info from the interwebs:

[Cape May Court House is inside the Middle Township](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS9F8.png)

Here’s another:
42 Wellington Drive
Long Valley, NJ  07853

It’s an option in the dropdown

[Long Valley in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZZM8.png)

But it populates another township, which again is not a deliverable address according to Shippo/UPS shipping integration.

[Populates with Washington Township](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnkfT.png)

And what google says about these two:

[Long Valley is a census-designated place inside Washington Township](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4kgq.png)

We are using the default Maps API code which uses 'locality' to fill the city field:

```
var placeSearch, txtaddress1,txtsaddress1;
        var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name' 
        };
        
        
      function initAutocomplete() {
      
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        var options = {
          types: ['address'],
          //componentRestrictions: {country: ["us","ca"]}
          componentRestrictions: {country: ["us","gu","pr","vi","um"]}
         };
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('txtaddress1')),options);

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        
        autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('txtsaddress1')),options);
        autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress2);
        
      }   
      
      function fillInAddress() {
      
       const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       
       var AL_zip = false;
        var addr = "";
        var postcode= "";
        var countrycode = "";
        //console.log(place);
        
         for (const component of place.address_components) {
            const componentType = component.types[0]
            
            switch (componentType) {
              case "street_number": {
                addr =(component.long_name);
                break;
                }
                
            case "route": {
                addr += " " +  component.short_name;
                $("#txtaddress1").val(addr);
                break;
              }
              case "locality":{         
                
                $("#txtcity").val(component.long_name);
                break;
                }
              case "administrative_area_level_1": {             
                $("#txtstate").val(component.short_name);               
                break;
              }
              case "postal_code": {
                postcode = component.short_name;
                $("#txtzipcode").val(postcode);
                break;
              }
              case "postal_code_suffix": {
                postcode = postcode + "-" + component.short_name;
                $("#txtzipcode").val(postcode);
                break;
              }
              case "country": {                     
                
                if (component.short_name=="US")
                {
                    countrycode="001"
                }   
                if (component.short_name=="GU")
                {
                    countrycode="260"
                    $("#txtstate").val("GU");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="PR")
                {
                    countrycode="272";
                    $("#txtstate").val("PR");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="VI")
                {                   
                    countrycode="278";
                    $("#txtstate").val("VI");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="UM")
                {
                    countrycode="313"
                }
                $("#billtocountry").val(countrycode);
                            
                break;
              }
         }
        
        }
      }
      
      function fillInAddress2() {
      
       const place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
       
       var AL_zip = false;
        var addr = "";
        var postcode= "";
        var countrycode = "";
        //console.log(place);
        
         for (const component of place.address_components) {
            const componentType = component.types[0]
            
            switch (componentType) {
              case "street_number": {
                addr =(component.long_name);
                break;
                }
                
            case "route": {
                addr += " " +  component.short_name;
                $("#txtsaddress1").val(addr);
                break;
              }
              case "locality":{         
                
                $("#txtscity").val(component.long_name);
                break;
                }
              case "administrative_area_level_1": {             
                $("#txtsstate").val(component.short_name);              
                break;
              }
              case "postal_code": {
                postcode = component.short_name;
                $("#txtszipcode").val(postcode);
                break;
              }
              case "postal_code_suffix": {
                postcode = postcode + "-" + component.short_name;
                $("#txtszipcode").val(postcode);
                break;
              }
              case "country": {                     
                
                if (component.short_name=="US")
                {
                    countrycode="001"
                }   
                if (component.short_name=="GU")
                {
                    countrycode="260"
                    $("#txtsstate").val("GU");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="PR")
                {
                    countrycode="272";
                    $("#txtsstate").val("PR");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="VI")
                {                   
                    countrycode="278";
                    $("#txtsstate").val("VI");
                }
                
                if (component.short_name=="UM")
                {
                    countrycode="313"
                }
                $("#shiptocountry").val(countrycode);
```

It seems to be a widespread issue. I've been testing other ecommerce sites, and this happens on all of them. It even behaves like this on Google's example page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

The only site I've found so far that seems to use Google Maps API and doesn't have this behavior is JCPenney.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What does your code that populates that form look like? (most likely that code is picking a different field than you expect) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Added the code!